# How to fit a long statement/equation on default margins?

Tags: spacing, margins

How do i fit this statement on default margins?

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts, graphicx, verbatim, mathtools,amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs}

\begin{document}

    \[
    \binom{9}{2}p^2(1-p)^7 \binom{7}{3}({(1-(1-p)^2})^3({(1-p)^2})^4 \binom{4}{1}({(1-(1-p)^3})^1({(1-p)^3})^3 \binom{3}{0}p^0(1-p)^3
    \]


\end{document}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a possibility, combining `multline*` and the medium-size binomial coefficient from `nccmath`. There were also some spurious opening parentheses that I removed.

*Unrelated*: you don't have to load `amsmath` when you load `mathtools`.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.3pt}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{graphicx, verbatim, mathtools,amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{4ex}
    \begin{multline*}
    \mbinom{9}{2}p^2(1-p)^7 \mbinom{7}{3}\bigl(1-(1-p)^2\bigr)^3\bigl((1-p)^2\bigr)^4 \mbinom{4}{1} \cdot {}\\[-0.5ex]
  \cdot\bigl(1-(1-p)^3\bigr)^1\bigl((1-p)^3\bigr)^3 \mbinom{3}{0}p^0(1-p)^3
    \end{multline*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

replace (1-p)=q

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts, graphicx, verbatim, mathtools,amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs}

\begin{document}

    \[
    \binom{9}{2}p^2q^7 \binom{7}{3}({(1-(q)^2})^3({(q)^2})^4 \binom{4}{1}({(1- 
    (q)^3})^1({(q)^3})^3 \binom{3}{0}p^0(q)^3
    \]


\end{document}
```

Comment: i know 1-p = q however i want to show it how i asked. Thank you for your answer.